# Pattern in which the data processing time comes down on increasing the number of nodes in a Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

When using a Hadoop cluster to process data, on increasing the number of nodes, the level of parallelism increases and the processing time comes down. Suppose we start with a 3 node cluster, if we add a node, the processing time decreases and we can add more nodes this way. Is there a pattern in which this processing time will decrease as we keep increasing the number of nodes and would it stop decreasing once going beyond a certain number of nodes? I went through related thread which uses Spark [application time processing depending on the number of computing nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520841/application-time-processing-depending-on-the-number-of-computing-nodes) and it is mentioned that adding more nodes brings overhead. How can one know the optimal number of nodes for the Hadoop cluster in order to get the best performance in terms of processing time?
Thank You.

Comment: Honestly, this question is kinda too broad, because at the end of the day it depends on the input data (especially if the job's handling big data) and the programmed design of the job you are running. So if data are too big for your cluster or the job you wrote has certain "chokeholds" (like many instances of reducers, where this amount exceeds the number of cores/machines or multiple chain jobs), you can only be sure by actually testing out with different number of nodes and gradually bigger and bigger subsets of your input data and pick the case that works best.

Comment: Thanks. So, it includes testing the performance by increasing the number of nodes and checking.

Comment: You can make tests based on what you are trying to achieve, either by adding new nodes or just having the least execution time possible through parallelization, but for the first one you need to remember that you will eventually hit a threshold where the job can't be efficiently "break out" into parallel chunks anymore (as you could imagine, and as the answer on the question you linked says) due to communication overhead and/or having "too little" data and "too many" worker nodes.

Comment: More nodes isn't always the solution. It's actually cores/tasks that determine processing speeds along with memory/disk speeds and storage types (Parquet processes faster than plaintext + structured data more than unstructured). Related https://adamdrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html